# how to define a var from json to js?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a newbie in javascript and need your help.
I don't know what to do and how to do to make this working:
I have the following js and html code:

```js
var slides = ''; 
var slideImg = slider.images; 
var i;
for (var i=0; i<slider.images.length; i++) {
    slides += '<div id="slide'+i+'" class="slideEl" ><img src="'+slider.images[i].src+'"><div class="container-images"><a href="'+slider.images[i].CTA.link+'" class="cta-btn '+slider.images[i].CTA.position+'">'+slider.images[i].CTA.text+'</a></div></div>';
}
document.getElementById('slides').innerHTML = slides;
document.getElementById('slides').style.width = window.innerWidth * (slideImg.length) + 'px'; 

document.getElementById('slides').style.transitionDuration = slideImg[0].speed + 's';
document.getElementById('slides').style.left = 0;

var indexSlide = 0; 
function moveSlide(params) {
    var slideWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('slideEl')[0].offsetWidth; 
    document.getElementById('slides').style.transitionDuration = slideImg[0].speed + 's';
    var element = document.getElementById('slides');
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    var newPos = rect.left;
    if(params == 'right' && indexSlide < slideImg.length -1){ 
        newPos -= slideWidth;
        indexSlide++;
    } else if (params == 'left' && indexSlide > 0) {
        newPos += slideWidth;
        indexSlide--;
    }
    document.getElementById('slides').style.transitionDuration = slider.images[indexSlide].speed + 's';
    document.getElementById('slides').style.left = newPos + 'px';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>JS exercise</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="slides" class="slides"></div>
        <div class="container-slider">
            <span id="arrowLeft" class="arrow" onclick="moveSlide('left')">&lang;</span>
            <span id="arrowRight" class="arrow" onclick="moveSlide('right')">&rang;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
        <footer>Copyright © 2019</footer>

    <script language="javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.json"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and besides that, I have another file called data.json:

```
[{
    "autoplay" : "yes",
    "transition" : "slide",
    "images" :[
        {
            "src" : "https://some-img.jpg",                                                       
            "speed" : "1.5",
            "CTA" : { 
                "text" : "Join Now",
                "link" : "http://test.com",
                "position" : "bottom-right"
            }
        },
        {
            "src" : "https://some-img.jpg",                                                          
            "speed" : "1.5",
            "CTA" : { 
                "text" : "Join Now",
                "link" : "http://test.com",
                "position" : "bottom-right"
            }
        },
        {
            "src" : "https://some-img.jpg",                                                          
            "speed" : "1.5",
            "CTA" : { 
                "text" : "Join Now",
                "link" : "http://www.test.com",
                "position" : "bottom-right"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I get the slider var from json to javascript just to defined the length of the whole slider?

**EDIT(from answer):**

@Mrunmay Deswandikar, I've added this piece of code at the start of my script.js file:

```js
var xhttp = new xmlhttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://wip.2mo.ro/sandra/js-slider/js/data.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
  
var slides = ''; 
var slideImg = slider.images; 
.....
```

I got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttpRequest is not defined
    at script.js:1
(anonymous) @ script.js:1

What am I missing?

### Many thanks,

Sandra

Comment: script tags are not meant to load json data. Use fetch instead.

Comment: They provide some good examples here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Answer (score 2):

Script tags are not meant to be used to load json data. Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) instead.

```
fetch('js/data.json')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>{
   const slider = data.shift();
   /** rest of your code here */
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

Fetch by default uses promises, but if you prefer to use it with async/await (syntaxical sugar for Promises).

```
async function loadData(){
  const res = await fetch('/js/data.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  const slider = data.shift();
  /** rest of code here */
}

loadData().catch(err=>console.log(err);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from json, use Ajax request to load JSON file.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

This will get all the data of **data.json** file, into variable **data**.
If your data.json file is located at the same directory, else you can use releative path, but best way will be use server path, like,

```
xhttp.open("GET","https://yourwebsite/DIRECTORY/data.json",true);
```

Comment: This was the way a couple of years ago

Comment: Yes but its easy for a newbie to understand ! As in question also she has put that 

" I'm a newbie in javascript "

Comment: I believe that `fetch(url).then(r => r.json())` is easier to understand, and does the same as your code

Comment: Fetch is just sugar coating on xmlHttpRequest, under the hood both of them are same.

Comment: Perfect @SagarAgrawal